# ActivityIndicator with Webview Control Xamarin Forms not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have the following code, but it doesn't work properly.

```
 <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="webViewLayout">
                    <WebView x:Name="webcontentcontrol" Source="{Binding WebViewSource}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill"></WebView>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" 
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">

            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Style="{StaticResource ActivityIndicatorStyle}"/>

            <Label Text="Loading..." IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource ActivityIndicatorLabelStyle}"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Cs File Code is

```
 public AnnouncementPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindWebViewControl();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        webViewLayout.IsVisible = false;
        IsBusy= true;
    }
    private async void BindWebViewControl()
    {            
        var result = await _dataService.GetAnnouncement();
        webcontentcontrol.Source = result.Data.First().WebViewSource;
        IsBusy = false;
        webViewLayout.IsVisible = true;
    }
```

The problem is that the label "Loading..." is not hiding, and Activity Indicator doesn't display on the screen.

Comment: are you use INotifyPropertyChanged Interface?

Comment: Yeah, I have implemented

Comment: if you using binding context viewmodel then you need to declare your isBusy variable in your viewmodel and set Viewmodel.isBusy in xaml.cs but you can also do simple way see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as below and try hope its help:

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

        <StackLayout x:Name="stkWebview" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="webViewLayout">
                    <WebView x:Name="webcontentcontrol" Source="{Binding WebViewSource}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill"></WebView>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout x:Name="stkLoading" 
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">

            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="true" Style="{StaticResource ActivityIndicatorStyle}"/>

            <Label Text="Loading..." HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource ActivityIndicatorLabelStyle}"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Your code behind look like below :

```
public AnnouncementPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindWebViewControl();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        stkWebview.IsVisible = false;
        stkLoading.IsVisible = true;
    }
    private async void BindWebViewControl()
    {            
        var result = await _dataService.GetAnnouncement();
        webcontentcontrol.Source = result.Data.First().WebViewSource;
        stkWebview.IsVisible = true;
        stkLoading.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You... It Works Fine.